# dialog with radio buttons to shown selected option

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have a dialog with radio buttons. It has more than 100 values. When user selects a value and reopen the dialog, I want to show the user exactly the last option selected.

Eg. If user has selected option 60. I want to show user on screen options from 55 to 65.

Which means, I don't wat the user to scroll again down from the top to see the option he has selected.

Can someone please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: Are you sure you need 100 radio buttons and not a slider control or something?

Comment: yes, that is the requirement.  I have the slider to scroll up and down  as it is list view in the dialog. My question is how to show the selected item directly, instead of user scrolling from first option to see which one is selected

Comment: For this , Create custom screen with adaptor and load your values in the array list, get the posistion of the data when the user click and create new arraylist are rest the arraylist using this code "Collections.rotate(list.subList(j, k+1), -1);"

Answer (score 0):

I have used list view in dialog. just need to setSelection of list view.